# Python script runs manually but gives 'Resource deadlock avoided' error in crontab

Tags: python, cron, deadlock, oserror

When I run my python script manually from the terminal it runs fine. Within the crontab this is the error it gives.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/uswamazhar/test.py", line 19, in <module>
    d5x_df1 = pd.read_excel(latest_file[-1])

  File "/Users/uswamazhar/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/uswamazhar/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 457, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)

  File "/Users/uswamazhar/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1376, in __init__
    ext = inspect_excel_format(

  File "/Users/uswamazhar/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1255, in inspect_excel_format

    buf = stream.read(PEEK_SIZE)
OSError: [Errno 11] Resource deadlock avoided
```

This is my crontab:

```
15 * * * * echo "test" >> test_status.txt
15 * * * * cd
15 * * * * /Users/uswamazhar/opt/anaconda3/bin/python ~/test.py 1>test.out 2>test.err
```

I tried running it through a nano shellscript too, still get the same error.

Comment: Do you realize that those 4 commands will all be run simultaneously?  You're running `test.py` twice.  (Why?)  If the first pandas locks the file, that's a conflict.

Comment: Added the 3rd line by mistake, let me edit the original post.

Comment: This runs once an hour.  Does it take more than an hour to run?  Do you have this file open in Excel at the same time?  Is the Excel file on your local disk?

Comment: The script takes about 15 minutes to run. The file is not open on excel. The file is on Box(file sharing system) which is also accessible through my local disk.
Sometimes it will run without the deadlock and sometimes it doesn't I want the script to run once every day(I will change the crontab timestamp) but right now I am sure the file is not open anywhere, it's still giving the same error.

Comment: Box monitors all those files continuously looking for changes.  Perhaps you should copy the file to a temp directory, and read it from there.

Comment: Tried doing that with shutil.copy, runs into the same error as it tries to copy from the same box folder(these files are updated daily). However, when I try to run the script outside of the cronjob, it runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing exact same issue since upgrading Box (2.24.211+). Current workaround I've found is to mark the files/folders to be read as "Make Available Offline" in Box. It does defeat the purpose of using cloud storage though, if you have huge amount of data.

Comment: Confirmed. The issue came with OneDrive on my case where files were stored online.